# Error when trying to prototype a function iside a class

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

for some reason the i get a Unknown token '.' in the line with prototype, when i want to execute this in chrome.
But in my opinion it should be correct according to the mozilla docs.

```
var A = class {
    constructor(an){
            this.a = an;
    }
    tick(){
            a();

    }
    A.prototype.p0 = function(){
            console.log('p0');


    }    };
```

Comment: What docs specifically are you referring to?

Comment: If you are going to refer to a class inside itself you should use `this`. You should also prototype the class outside itself.

Comment: Two reasons why it's wrong: 1) you can only use valid symbol names there, and `.` isn't valid in a symbol name; 2) that's not how this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not correct. This is how you should write it:

```
var A = class {
    constructor(an) {
        this.a = an;
    }
    tick(){
        a();
    }
    p0() {
        console.log('p0');
    }
};
```

The whole point of the `class` syntactic sugar is to eliminate the need to manipulate prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

Uou do not seem to understand the use of `prototype`. If you are going to define the behavior of a class function inside the class body just write the function. `prototype` is used when you are defining/overriding a class function outside of the class body.

Also you might find this useful: if you are going to refer to a class inside itself you should use `this`